# Track changes in excel against previous version vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to track the changes made in an excel file used by multiple people. So far I have built the model (with help from stackoverflow) to save a version of itself within activeworkbook.path & "\Version Control".

The copy is saved when file opens and is named: date & time & activeworkbook.name

Currently it look at a range to determine if intersect then return the new value in sheet x cell y. How do I write the code to allow it to open the latest saved backup and give me in sheet x cell z the older versions value?

Code I have:

Track Changes:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Sheets("UserLog").Cells(1, 24) = IsBlank Then Exit Sub

Dim strAddress As String
Dim val
Dim dtmTime As Date
Dim Rw As Long

If Intersect(Target, Range("CheckRange5")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

dtmTime = Format(Now(), "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS")
val = Target.Value
strAddress = Target.Address

Rw = Sheets("UserLog").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
With Sheets("UserLog")
    .Cells(Rw, 4) = strAddress
    .Cells(Rw, 5) = val
    .Cells(Rw, 6) = dtmTime
    .Cells(Rw, 7) = Environ("Username")
    .Cells(Rw, 8) = "SCI - SDBD"
End With

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Saving the File:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim MyDate
MyDate = Date
Dim MyTime
MyTime = Time
Dim TestStr As String
TestStr = Format(MyTime, "hhmmss")
Dim Test1Str As String
Test1Str = Format(MyDate, "YYYY-MM-DD")
xxPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

Application.DisplayAlerts = False


ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=xxPath & "\Version Control" & "\" & Test1Str & " " & TestStr & " " & ActiveWorkbook.Name
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Why not just use the built in Track Changes feature within Excel?  It's in the Review tab -> Track Changes

Comment: Hello, wasn't sure how it worked as the file is a shared file where I need all the details of the user and the changes added into a log  format in another sheet or file. As there can be changes made by multiple users at different time for the time place, I thought it be easier this way... Maybe I am wrong... Also I don't want the changes to be seen in the sheet where the change was made.... and I don't know if it makes any difference but we run different versions of excel at work, from 2007 - 2016